# jQuery event ajax dispatching

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery is there clever/shorthand way of tacking on an identifier to some general ajax events?

To explain, i am creating some functionality that is split between two seperate pieces of functionality: module A and module B.  Module A, along with some other things, is primarily responsible for an ajax call. Module B is responsible for frontend dom work, after module a has finished and the ajax call has been returned.

I am currently simply triggering events for each of the ajax functions:

- beforeSend
- success
- complete
- error

So module has this code (among other stuff):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'myajaxurl',
    beforeSend : function() {
        $('#form').trigger('module_a_before_send');
    },
    success: function(response) {
       $('#form').trigger('module_a_success');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#form').trigger('module_a_complete');
    },
    error: function(textStatus) {
        $('#form').trigger('module_a_error');
    },
    timeout: 3000
});
```

Comment: what is the purpose of .trigger? is it just a way to call functions? in other words is module_a_complete name of a function?

Comment: I want to let module b know when certain parts of the module a ajax call are occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the data option to send a value to the serverside to identify the ajax call:

```
var data = if some event ? attach some value : if not attach other value etc,
    elem = $('#form');
$.ajax({
    url: 'myajaxurl',
    data: data,
    beforeSend : function() {
        elem.trigger('module_a_before_send');
    },
    success: function(response) {
       elem.trigger('module_a_success');
    },
    complete: function() {
        elem.trigger('module_a_complete');
    },
    error: function(textStatus) {
        elem.trigger('module_a_error');
    },
    timeout: 3000
});
```

How to catch the data depends on the serverside language used, but for something like PHP it would be in the `$_POST` global.

Comment: Sorry, i think my explenation may be confusing matters.  Basically, i am looking for a nicer way of simply wrapping the $.ajax function just to trigger my custom event names.

Comment: @Brian - there probably are ways to use promises or just calling a function on each event handler etc. But this is the way it's normally done, and I don't see a reason to do something else to pretty up the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about the problem. If you need some comunication between modules you can use the extra data parameter that you can pass to trigger (see http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$(elem).trigger('my-custom-event', {id:1})
```

and the coresponding event handler

```
$(elem).bind('my-custom-event', function(event, data) {});
```

Another way would be to create your own custom event

```
var event = $.Event('my-custom-event',{id:1})
$(elem).trigger(event)
```

in this way you directly add the properties from the map to the jQuery event object.

Comment: Hi, the problem is i want to know if there is a built in way to tack on an identifier to some ajax events so i dont have to manually trigger an event on each ajax function: beforeSend, success etc.

Comment: No there is'nt. The plain JS XMLHttpRequest has an onreadystate event, but that was dropped from jQuery since the done, always and fail callbacks will give you exactly the same with less trouble, and that's basically what you're already doing.